# What are pros and cons of different quick release systems?

Tags: tripod, quick-release

Some overlooked detail in photography are quick release systems. I found it tough to get good information about them, and since they tend to be rather expensive I'd like to hear pros and cons of different quick release systems and brands.

Comment: Discussion questions like this aren't really suitable for the Stack Exchange system as there's no chance of there being one acceptable answer. If you'd asked for the advantages of System A over System B then that would have been a better question.

Comment: I kind of agree with @ChrisF on this. This question is broad and will be difficult to come up with a answer without going into a lot of depth--we'd have to essentially go through all the different plate systems (Manfrotto has at least 5 different types of quick releases alone).

Comment: Well, the point was not to get one single answer, but instead to have informations on which the reader might be able to decide, which quick release system would fit his own style.
you think this is unattainable?

Comment: while the Stack Exchange engine *can* be used for this sort of list question it's not really what it's built for. The votes and acceptance of one answer are designed to make the correct answer (well the answer that solved the problem) bubble to the top of the list.

Comment: @ChrisF, I wanted pro/con of the systems, so one can make an educated dicision. I didn't ask for "the best" system, since such does not exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have any interest in extra tripod head gear, whether it be panoramic heads, macro focus rails, L-brackets or anything else in that space then your first concern is going to be interoperability and standardization.

Unfortunately the quick release market is horribly fragmented with each major tripod brand having several unique systems.

To the degree that there is any interoperability and standardization at all, the Arca-Swiss style brackets are clearly the leader.

Notably Arca-Swiss style is now the standard system for the larger third party tripod accessory vendors like [Really Right Stuff](https://www.reallyrightstuff.com/) and [Nodal Ninja](http://www.nodalninja.com/).

Comment: Arca swiss system may not be "the" standard, it seems to be the "most common".

Answer (score 4):

I have got a [Manfrotto 488RC4 ball head](http://manfrotto.com.br/midi-ball-head-with-rc4-rapid-connect-system.html) which has a [410PL quick release plate](https://www.manfrotto.com/accessory-plate-with-1-4-and-3-8-screws) and their system works really well.

Pros:

- The plate is quite large and therefore supports large/heavy cameras perfectly.
- The quick release has a secondary safety hatch so you cannot release it accidentally when you bump the normal hatch into something.
- The plate attaches very easily to the base. You only need one hand (that is holding the camera) and snap the camera/plate right into position.

Cons:

- Since the plate is quite large it is not comfortable shooting handheld in portrait orientation with a battery grip attached.

Comment: +1 for the RC4. I modded my 468GM to use the RC4, and it's awesome.